# Does $X \otimes I + I \otimes Y = f I \otimes I$ imply $X = Y = (f/2)I$?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products

For $N\times N$ matrix $X$ and $M \times M$ matrix $Y$, suppose the following equation is obeyed:
$$
X \otimes I_{M \times M} + I_{N \times N} \otimes Y = f I_{N \times N} \otimes I_{M \times M}
$$
for some number $f$. Does this imply that the solution is $X = (f/2) I_{N \times N}$ and $Y = (f/2) I_{M \times M}$?

Comment: Have you considered the simplest case, $M = N = 1$?

Comment: Ah I see, it is clearly not true given this obvious example. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly what you meant to avoid this counterexample is $X = \alpha I_{N \times N}$ and $Y = (f-\alpha) I_{M \times M}$ where $\alpha$ is a free parameter, not necessarily $f/2$.

Comment: The condition implies that $X=xI$ and $Y=yI$ for some $x$ and $y$ such that $x+y=f$.